# Prevent timeout from waiting for subprocesses

Tags: java, linux, timeout

I've got a shell script which repeatedly calls a java process with different arguments. It uses timeout to wait for some amount of seconds before assuming a call has failed and moving on to the next one. I am certain that the java process is finishing in much less time than the allotted timeout: when I run it individually with the arguments rather than using this script, it consistently terminates very quickly. However, from the script it always times out.

My java process launches subprocesses, and this only became and issue once I started doing this, so I'm fairly confident this is the issue. I am wondering if there is a way to be launching subprocesses from the java process such that as long as the actual java process terminates, the timeout call will return.

Comment: How does your Java code wait until the subprocess is complete (or does it wait at all?) You can use `process.waitFor()` to wait until a spawned Process is done.

Comment: I don't wait for the subprocess to complete (I am using processbuilder, and do not call waitfor). The whole issue (I think) is that the subprocesses are still running, and may not terminate for a little while, but I want the timeout call to still progress once the main java process finishes